# Why did Mr Weasley ask Mr And Mrs Granger how bus stops work?

Tags: harry-potter, magic

Why did Mr Weasley ask Mr And Mrs Granger how bus stops Work in *Chamber of Secrets*. Well i am having trouble understanding why he would do this, because **he had already traveled on the Knight bus**.

Why would he ask Mr Granger about bus stops?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Aside from the name and external appearance, the knight bus experience hardly resembles a muggle bus at all. It appears as soon as you call it, it teleports to (near) where it needs to go, inanimate objects jump out of its way, etc. that's quite different from a muggle bus where you go to the stop, wait an indeterminate amount of time, get on, deposit your bus token, and it just mundanely drives like any other muggle vehicle to the next (predetermined) stop.

Comment: In addition, questions such as "How do you make the bus come to the stop?" and "How do you make the bus go to where you want it to go?" are possible from that angle.

Answer (score 5):

Mr. Weasley only knows the wizarding way of transportation, which includes the Knight Bus. The Knight Bus is very much unlike public transportation because it shows up as soon as a wizard or witch holds out his/her wand hand, whereas a muggle bus has a specific schedule that does not change to accommodate one or two people. 
The Knight Bus also goes directly to the location you want it to, but a muggle bus has specified stops and muggles have to know exactly how to get where they're going once they get off; it could be the next street over, or it could be five blocks away because the bus doesn't go into that neighbourhood. 
You could also compare this with the car that Mr. Weasley had to drive to Kings Cross and that Ron and Harry flew to Hogwarts in *The Chamber of Secrets.* Mr. Weasley wasn't used to driving like a muggle, and he had actually wanted to use the Invisibility Booster that he had installed to fly the car to Kings Cross, mainly because they were running late. It could also be inferred that Arthur did not want to drive the muggle way because he was not used to it.

Answer (score -1):

Again the other answers assume that JKR is infallible. The situation we have here, is that As Far As We Know, in *Chamber of Secrets* the Knight Bus doesn't exist. This question is a classic example of how JKR later adds in something she had previously excluded in other statements through her books. A similar example is Hagrid's use of flying in *Sorcerer's Stone*.

Also in canon we have no idea if Mr. Weasley had actually taken the knight bus before.

Comment: This answer seems based more on bitterness than any real point...